# Is there an event fired right after a command finishes executing?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

In Bash, after you type in a command (e.g., `ls`), it will execute the command, which will write its standard output (if not redirected) to the terminal (in our example, the content of the current directory). After it's done, the control is returned to the user with a shell prompt in a new line.

I'm wondering if there is some sort of event fired right after the command finishes running and before the command prompt starts in a new line, which can be captured programmatically (i.e., with shell script).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the shell variable `PROMPT_COMMAND` to a command,
then that command will be executed every time the shell is about to issue a (primary) prompt. 
For example,

```
% ls
file1
file2
% PROMPT_COMMAND=date
Thu, Nov 20, 2014  1:23:42 PM
% ls
file1
file2
Thu, Nov 20, 2014  1:23:45 PM
%
```

This can be a program, a script, or whatever.